# Do list separated by date PHP

Tags: php, list, foreach, notifications

I need your help.

I'm creating a reporting system and I need it to list all the reports that groups only in blocks according to the date.

ex:

Today - May 23
a result
result 2

May 22
result 3
4 results
5 results

May 21
6 results
7 results

The listing I can do it quietly, the problem is to distinguish the date to be right within the respective block.

My code:

```
<?php
$data_anterior = "0000-00-00";
$data_hoje = date("Y-m-d");
//Se houverem registros
foreach($notificacoes AS $notif) :
?>

<?
//Verifica a data e faz o tratamento
$data_cadastro = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($notif->data_cadastro));
?>                        

<?php if($data_cadastro == $data_hoje && $data_anterior != $data_cadastro) { ?>

<h4>Hoje <span><?php echo $CI->funcoes->data_abreviada($data_cadastro); ?></span></h4>
<ul class="list-notificacoes">

<?php } ?>


<?php if($data_cadastro < $data_hoje && $data_anterior != $data_cadastro) { ?>

<div class="graybox">
        <header class="clearfix">
                <h4><?php echo $CI->funcoes->data_abreviada($data_cadastro); ?></h4>
                <a href="" class="btnGrayBox ir">Toggle</a>
        </header>
        <ul class="list-notificacoes">

<?php } ?>



<li class="clearfix">
    <div class="box-left">
        <span class="icon-lista-ate">&nbsp;</span>
        <a href=""><?php echo stripslashes($usuario->nome); ?></a>
        <span>fez tal tarefa</span>
        <a href=""><?php echo stripslashes($evento->titulo); ?></a>
    </div>
    <div class="box-right">
        <span><?php echo date("H:i", strtotime($notif->data_cadastro)); ?></span>
        <a class="icon-close ir" href="">Excluir</a>
    </div>
</li>


<?php if($data_cadastro == $data_hoje && $data_anterior != $data_cadastro) { ?>
</ul>
<?php } ?>

<?php if($data_cadastro < $data_hoje && $data_anterior != $data_cadastro) { ?>
</ul>
</div>
<?php } ?>


<?php $data_anterior = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($notif->data_cadastro)); ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

My problem is with the closing of the blocks and thus it breaks the code.

There's something wrong in my IF, someone help me?

Comment: You have a lot of php embedded in HTML. I would suggest making things a bit more simple and have the php generate the HTML code using echo's.

Comment: @Halan Schlickmann, use alternate PHP syntax esp.for HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a typo.

After the foreach statement "php" is missing from the opening tag:

```
<? instead of 
<?php 

//Verifica a data e faz o tratamento
$data_cadastro = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($notif->data_cadastro));
?>)
```

See if this fixes your problem.